# MongoDB crashes on serial update (pymongo)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I wrote a simple script to do a collection-wide update on my `events` collection inside my `motivate_testing` db. Here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from pymongo import MongoClient

from apps.motiv8 import models

# Mongo setup
client = MongoClient()
db = client[settings.MONGO_DB_NAME]

for event in db.events.find():
    try:
        course = models.Course.objects.get(id=event['course_id'])
    except:
        continue
    organization = course.organization
    db.events.update({"course": event['course_id']}, {"$set": {"organization_id": int(organization.id)} })
```

Every time I run this, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./add_org_to_events_db.py", line 27, in <module>
    db.events.update({"course": event['course_id']}, {"$set": {"organization_id": int(organization.id)} })
  File "/opt/motiv8/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 487, in update
    check_keys, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
  File "/opt/motiv8/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 956, in _send_message
    sock_info = self.__socket()
  File "/opt/motiv8/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 773, in __socket
    "%s %s" % (host_details, str(why)))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Which crashes mongo entirely. I have about 9000 records inside this collection. What am I doing wrong? For a database touted for its "speed" and "concurrency," MongoDB is severely disappointing me. It seems as if I'm running the connection into the ground.

Comment: Can you grab the update query (with the values as sent) and try it from the MongoDB console?

Comment: Also, which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: Can you please post the last few lines of the server's mongod.log? It will include the reason for the crash there, with a C++ traceback.